# How to indicate graphically that two sides are of equal length?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm using tikz to draw two triangles, e.g.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
  \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
  \coordinate (B) at ($(A)+(330:3)$);
  \coordinate (C) at ($(A)+(230:4)$);
  \draw (A) node[above]{$A$} --(B) node[right]{$B$} -- (C) node[left]{$C$} --cycle;
  \tkzMarkAngle[size=1.0](C,A,B)

  \begin{scope}[rotate=75] 
    \coordinate (A) at (0,-5);
    \coordinate (B) at ($(A)+(330:3)$);
    \coordinate (C) at ($(A)+(230:4)$);
    \draw (A) node[above]{$A$} --(B) node[right]{$B$} -- (C) node[left]{$C$} --cycle;
    \tkzMarkAngle[size=1.0](C,A,B)
  \end{scope}  
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The two triangles are congruent and, as such, I'd like to use the normal notation to indicate that, i.e. a single tick on each of the lines *AB* on each triangle and a double tick on each of the lines *AC*.

I could add a length, e.g. *x* or *y* to each, but that's not an ideal solution.

I've tried adding in a midway point in the draw command to use a '-' or an '=', but that only really works if the line is horizontal or vertical otherwise I have to calculate the angle, which doesn't seem right.

Am I just missing out some simple instruction because I, maybe, just don't know the correct term for those marks?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436). For future reference, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

This is especially important for `tikz` as there are numerous libraries.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz,tkz-euclide}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetkzobj{all}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
  \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
  \coordinate (B) at ($(A)+(330:3)$);
  \coordinate (C) at ($(A)+(230:4)$);
  \draw (A) node[above]{$A$} --(B) node[right]{$B$} -- (C) node[left]{$C$} --cycle;
  \tkzMarkAngle[size=1.0](C,A,B)
  \tkzMarkSegment[color=blue,pos=.5,mark=||](A,C) 
  \tkzMarkSegment[color=red,pos=.5,mark=s|](A,B) 
  \begin{scope}[rotate=75] 
    \coordinate (A) at (0,-5);
    \coordinate (B) at ($(A)+(330:3)$);
    \coordinate (C) at ($(A)+(230:4)$);
    \draw (A) node[above]{$A$} --(B) node[right]{$B$} -- (C) node[left]{$C$} --cycle;
    \tkzMarkAngle[size=1.0](C,A,B)
    \tkzMarkSegment[color=blue,pos=.5,mark=||](A,C)
    \tkzMarkSegment[color=red,pos=.5,mark=s|](A,B)
  \end{scope}  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ah-hah - \tkzMarkSegment - that's the one! Thanks.

Comment: Do you know if there's a way to get those marks perpendicular to their segments? The marks on `AB` in each figure look weird. Or is `mark=s|` causing that?

Comment: Use `\tkzMarkSegment[color=red,pos=.5,mark=|](A,B)`